# How to make .png images the same size in html

Tags: html, css

I have the following code set for 2 different images on my site.

Boys logo:

```
<img src="logo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="HTML tag" style="max-width: 100; max-height: 100;">
```

Girls logo:

```
<img src="girlslogo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="HTML tag" style="max-width: 100; max-height: 100;">
```

I have set them both to be the same size but they girls logo looks much bigger. I have uploaded it to my site. Look at the girls logo [here](https://acanhs.org/girlshome.html) and the boys logo [here](https://acanhs.org/boyshome.html) the logo is at the top left corner of the screen. I have set a max height and width to both of them. Why isn't it capping the images?

Comment: I don't generally use inline style, but I think you still need units on your sizes e.g. `100px` or `100%`

Comment: Does the boys image have space around the logo in the image itself?

Comment: @DBS I have tried both. I had the same result

Comment: @j09691 Nope its a png it doesn't have space around it

Comment: @hammode The boy's logo has white around it. https://acanhs.org/logo.png And by the way, the style won't work without adding a unit.

Comment: @AmauryHanser is their a workaround this?

Comment: Well, recreate the asset for the logo, that's the simplest solution

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Look, your logo has whitespace around it.

Answer (score 1):

Your **Boys logo** image contains white space around it thats why it appears to be smaller than **girls logo**.
You can see for it yourself by running the code below or looking at the image result attached below.

*If you want to use the same logo without the whitespace you can extract the foreground of the image using this [website](https://www.remove.bg/t/change-background) and then download it back as a png which now you can use in your html.*

```
<img src="https://acanhs.org/logo.png" style="border:2px solid black" width=100 height=100/>
<img src="https://acanhs.org/girlslogo.png" style="border:2px solid black" width=100 height=100/>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj4WB.jpg